# How to generate all possible sentence from given tokens in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to generate all possible sentences from given token. It is a transliteration program. I have various possibilities for each token to be transliterated and I want to generate all possible sentences. e.g. if sentence is token1 token2 token3 and supposing token1 can be represented in 3 ways after transliteration, token2 can be represented by 2 ways and token3 can be represented by 4 ways then total possible sentences are 24. I am developed a general tree and then perform depth first traversal to generate all possible sentences. the problem is when sentence become long, the number of possibilities increases and I got "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error.

Is there any other way to generate all possible sentences?? At some instances I need to generate millions of sentences. Please Help!!!

Comment: can u explain your question with some example?

Comment: When you say "generate", I assume you hold them all at one in memory - who don't you write them out in a file instead?

Comment: it can be generated but that is not the correct way to create a translator, the more the tokens are the more it will produces meaningless sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate them all at once like that.
Depending on what you need them for, you should either do whatever that is or write them to a file.

Another thought, that still might not work, would be to not store every possible value but store a set of references/relationships. You can make this much more complex with n-grams and mMrkov chains, or simply have a a set of references, or even just have a list of array indexes.

So besides using storage space as a memory buffer, you can conceptualize instead of foo calling gen for the full set, have gen call foo after each one is generated.

[EDIT: looking back on this, (I was interested to see any other answers) I want to clarify that the function foo is whatever you're using them for and the function gen generates them (just in case it isn't clear, and especially for anyone who's first language isn't english)]